# Property does not have corresponding setter in class Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface while change checkout step

Tags: magento2, module, eav, shipping-address, extension-attributes

1 - I add a eav attribute to customer_address

```
$attributesInfo = [
    'reference' => [
         'label' => 'Reference',
         'type' => 'varchar',
         'input' => 'text',
         'position' => 100,
         'visible' => true,
         'required' => false,
    ],
];

foreach ($attributesInfo as $attributeCode => $attributeParams) {
    $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', $attributeCode, $attributeParams);
}
```

2 - I added the extension attribute in my module

```
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
    <attribute code="reference" type="string"/>
</extension_attributes>
```

In my requirejs-config.js I override some javascript file to add reference field

```
var config = {
"map": {
    "*": {
        "Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default" : "Agr_Checkout/js/shipping-save-processor-default-override",
        "Magento_Customer/js/model/customer/address" : "Agr_Checkout/js/model/customer/address",
        "Magento_Checkout/js/model/address-converter" : "Agr_Checkout/js/model/address-converter",
        "Magento_Checkout/js/model/new-customer-address" : "Agr_Checkout/js/model/new-customer-address"
    }
}
```

3 - I confirm that the reference field is sending in address

[image]

4 - When i send my shipping information (Click on Next) I'm getting this error: **"Property "Reference" does not have corresponding setter in class "Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface"."**

[image]

I already do:
 - Clean and flush magento cache
 - Run setup:upgrade
 - Run setup:di:compile

**What I'm doing wrong?**

Comment: Did the answer below work?

Comment: I solved by hard sql insertion, executing a script for update de reference with the address_id, I know is wrong but I was a little rushed, i will test and give you a feedback later.

Comment: I don't think you can be blamed... apparently you can only add custom_attributes in Enterprise and so far I have found no "easily customisable checkout" way around this.

Comment: any update regarding?

Comment: @allamgr i am also facing same issue with the new customer address attribute did u get solution for this? can u share me your thoughts on this. https://prnt.sc/iovkp2

Comment: @NagarajuKasa show me how are u adding the city_id attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up attributes in an eav setup or upgrade script works best, and will automatically add to forms you request to add it to.

```
    class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
    {
        private $_eavSetupFactory;
        private $_eavConfig;
        private $_attributeResource;
        protected $_logger;

        public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, Config $eavConfig, Attribute $attributeResource, Monolog $logger)
        {
            $this->_eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
            $this->_eavConfig = $eavConfig;
            $this->_attributeResource = $attributeResource;
            $this->_logger = $logger;
        }

        public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
        {
            $eavSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $addressAttributes = [
        'attribute1' => [
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'attribute1',
            'input' => 'text',
            'unique' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'position' => 100,
            'system' => false,
            'adminhtml_only' => 0
        ],
        'attribute2' => [
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'attribute2',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'position' => 110,
            'system' => false,
            'adminhtml_only' => 1
        ]
    ];

    $usedInFormsAddress = [
            'adminhtml_customer_address',
            'customer_address_edit',
            'customer_register_address'
        ];

    foreach ($addressAttributes as $code => $options) {
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            'customer_address',
            $code,
            $options
        );

        try {
            $attribute = $this->_eavConfig->getAttribute('customer_address', $code);
            $attribute->setData(
                'used_in_forms',
                $usedInFormsAddress
            );
            $this->_attributeResource->save($attribute);
        } catch (LocalizedException $exception) {
            $this->_logger->critical($exception->getMessage());
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            $this->_logger->critical($exception->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

[image]

This code here will add to the forms and there won't be any issue saving or going to next step

```
$usedInFormsAddress = [
            'adminhtml_customer_address',
            'customer_address_edit',
            'customer_register_address'
        ];

try {
            $attribute = $this->_eavConfig->getAttribute('customer_address', $code);
            $attribute->setData(
                'used_in_forms',
                $usedInFormsAddress
            );
            $this->_attributeResource->save($attribute);
        } catch (LocalizedException $exception) {
            $this->_logger->critical($exception->getMessage());
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            $this->_logger->critical($exception->getMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it via custom attributes.

Example:

```
...
 custom_attribute: [{"attribute_code": "reference", "value": "Your value"}]
...
```

Comment: Did you ever get this to work or is it only an experiment?

Comment: I got it working

Comment: With community edition? I would greatly appreciate it, even with bounty if you could demonstrate how.

Comment: It was with Magento2 Enterprise Edition on a custom detached frontend checkout procedure. I have to search that code. It is an old work.

Comment: Please show me if you find it, but I don't think it's available.

Comment: @Phoenix128_RiccardoT i am facing same issue can you please provide me any alternative solution for this thanks. i have tried u r solution but no luck whether we need to customize for this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

how do you pass the attribute in the request? you can check browser console like that

```
{
    ...
    extension_attributes: {
         reference: "value"
    }
}
```

It's correct. You can remove var folder and generated folder
 **var/cache var/page_cache var/view_proceed and generated/**.